# R: Plotting OOB error rate

Tags: r, plot, machine-learning, random-forest

I'm currently working with Random Forest classification model. Im using the `randomForest` package. Since I'm working with a total of 11 different classes, using the `plot()` fuction results in plot of 12 error rates - the class error rates and the OOB error rate. Is there a way to only plot the OOB error rate?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the variable you receive from the `randomForest` function is called `someModel`, you have all the information in it saved.

Your `confusion Matrix` contains a variable, called `err.rate` which you access with the `$` sign.  The `err.rate` is stored in a matrix where the first column is the `OOB Error`. Each class gets its own column. Try `str(someModel$err.rate)`.

To access the `err.rate` do this `someModel $err.rate[,1]`, for plotting simply `plot(myModel $err.rate[,1])`.

Comment: This approach of accessing the model's `err.rate` variable also works for the `rfsrc` package.